# The use of "ever since"

Tags: grammaticality

I have been reading threads on this site, but I still have one question:

Is it possible to say:

I didn't like travelling ever since I came back from Paris (for example)?

Comment: No.  You need to use the present perfect tense here:  "I haven't liked".

Comment: ...or more awkwardly "I didn't like travelling ever since I had come back from Paris". The example you give would commonly be reckoned incorrect, but I imagine you might hear similar things sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

*Didn't* implies something that has ended, in this case traveling.  But *ever since* implies something that is still continuing.  The two implications are contradictory, and so it feels awkward.

"I *haven't* liked traveling ever since I came back from Paris"  - good.

"I didn't like traveling after I came back from Paris, but then I went to watch the eclipse in Brazil with Jane, and now I like it again."  - good.